# how to add pause or skip pause in script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, networking, server

Hello I have a script that I'm creating for work and got requested to add a feature for scalability. I currently have a pause after every request but I don't know how to add a skip pause feature. I left my code to show the basic function of what I'm doing to provide further info. On the top I mainly have functions and at the bottom are the function actions and pauses.

```
    #!/bin/bash
    # Basic Linux host info script
    # Matthew Morcaldi 2015
    # TODO: Getops & HP Support

    # Config ------------------------------------------------
outfile="linux_info.txt"
#--------------------------------------------------------

#### uncomment (set -x) for debug 
# set -x 


checkroot() { 
    if [ $UID -ne 0 ] ; then
        echo "User has insufficient privilege."
        exit 4
    fi
}

header() { 
    echo '' | tee -a $outfile
    echo '----------------------' | tee -a $outfile
    echo "[*] $title" | tee -a $outfile
    echo '----------------------' | tee -a $outfile
}

function pause(){
   read -p "$*"
}


display_os() { 
    title="System"
    header $title
    dmidecode -t 1 | grep -i 'serial' | sed 's/^ *//' | tee  $outfile
    cat /etc/*-release | tee -a $outfile
    dmidecode -t system -q | egrep -i 'Manufacturer: |Product|UUID' | \
    sed 's/^ *//' | tee -a $outfile
    ipmitool bmc info | egrep -i 'Firmware revision' | tee  -a $outfile
    dmidecode -t bios -q | egrep -i 'version|vendor' | \
    sed 's/^ *//' | tee -a $outfile
}

display_network_oob() { 
    title="Drac-Info"
    header $title
    ipmitool lan print | egrep -i 'IP Address|MAC Address|Default Gateway IP|Subnet Mask' | tee -a $outfile
}

display_networking() {
    title="Networking"
    header $title
    ifconfig -a | tee -a $outfile
}

display_bonding() { 
    if [ -f /proc/net/bonding/bond0 ] ; then
        title="Bonding"
        header $title
        cat /proc/net/bonding/bond0 | sed 's/^ *//' | tee -a $outfile
    fi
}

display_switch_info() { 
    if [ -f /usr/sbin/lldpctl ] ; then
        title="Switch-Port-Information"
        header $title
        lldpctl | egrep '(Interface|VLAN|PortDescr|SysName)' | \
        sed 's/^ *//' | tee -a $outfile
        else
            echo "Switch file LLDPCTL does not exist skipping"
    fi
}

show_disks_dell() {
    if [ -f /opt/MegaRAID/MegaCli/MegaCli64 ] ; then 
        title="Dell-Raid"
        header $title
        /opt/MegaRAID/MegaCli/MegaCli64 -PDList -aAll |  \
        egrep -i 'count|^Device Id: |firmware state' |  \
        grep -v 'Count: 0' | \
        perl -p -e 's/Firmware state: (.*)$/Firmware state: $1\n/' | tee -a $outfile
        else
            echo "skipping Dell disk check"
     fi
}

show_battery_dell() { 
    if [ -f /opt/MegaRAID/MegaCli/MegaCli64 ]; then
        title="Dell-Battery"
        header $title
        /opt/MegaRAID/MegaCli/MegaCli64 -AdpBbuCmd -GetBbuStatus -a0 | \
        egrep -i 'isSOHGood|Charger Status|Capacity|Relative|Charging' | \
        sed 's/^ *//' | tee -a $outfile
        else
            echo "skipping Dell battery check"
    fi
}

show_disks_hp() { 
    if [ -f /usr/sbin/hpacucli ]; then
        title="HP-Raid"
        header $title
        hpacucli ctrl all show config detail | \
        sed 's/^ *//' | tee -a $outfile 
    else
        echo "skipping HP disk check"
    fi
}

show_battery_hp() { 
    if [ -f /usr/sbin/hpacucli ]; then
        title="HP-Battery"
        header $title
        hpacucli ctrl all show status | \
        sed 's/^ *//' | tee -a $outfile
    else
        echo "skipping HP battery check"
    fi
}

display_dimms() {
    title="Memory"
    header $title
    cat /proc/meminfo|grep MemTotal >> $outfile
    free -g | tee -a $outfile
}

sel_list() {
    title="SEL"
    header $title
    ipmitool sel elist | tee -a $outfile
}
# Where the magic happens -------------------------------------
# TODO: Add Optarg Support
# http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/getopts_tutorial
# comment out below to skip 




pause 'Press [Enter] key to continue. ..'
service ipmi start 
pause 'Press [Enter] key to continue. ..'
display_os
pause 'Press [Enter] key to continue. ..'
display_network_oob
pause 'Press [Enter] key to continue. ..'
display_networking
pause 'Press [Enter] key to continue. ..'
display_bonding
pause 'Press [Enter] key to continue. ..'
display_dimms
pause 'Press [Enter] key to continue. ..'
display_switch_info
pause 'Press [Enter] key to continue. ..'
sel_list
pause 'Press [Enter] key to continue. ..'
show_disks_hp
pause 'Press [Enter] key to continue. ..'
show_battery_hp
pause 'Press [Enter] key to continue. ..'
show_disks_dell
pause 'Press [Enter] key to continue. ..'
show_battery_dell
pause 'Press [Enter] key to continue. ..'
service ipmi stop


cat << "EOF"
          _ _,---._
       ,-','       `-.___
      /-;'               `._
     /\/          ._   _,'o \
    ( /\       _,--'\,','"`. )
     |\      ,'o     \'    //\
     |      \        /   ,--'""`-.
     :       \_    _/ ,-'         `-._
      \        `--'  /                )
       `.  \`._    ,'     ________,','
         .--`     ,'  ,--` __\___,;'
          \`.,-- ,' ,`_)--'  /`.,'
           \( ;  | | )      (`-/
             `--'| |)       |-/         
               | | |        | |
               | | |,.,-.   | |_
               | `./ /   )---`  )
              _|  /    ,',   ,-'
             ,'|_(    /-<._,' |--,
             |    `--'---.     \/ \
             |          / \    /\  \
           ,-^---._     |  \  /  \  \
        ,-'        \----'   \/    \--`.
       /            \              \   \
EOF
```

Comment: Add an if statement in your `pause` function to optionally skip the read?

Answer (score 1):

Change your `pause` function to return 0 (`true`) to skip, or 1 (`false`) to continue, and rename it to something more descriptive:

```
function shouldSkip {
  read -p "$*" line
  test "$line" = 'n' -o "$line" = 's'
  return $?
}
```

To use:

```
if ! shouldSkip 'Press [Enter] key to continue, [n] or [s] to skip "service ipmi start". ..'
then
  service ipmi start
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Special thanks to Danny Dagla. Posting the final script for global use.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Linux host info script [DONUTS]
# Matthew Morcaldi 2015
# Version 0.1.2 last update (1/19/2015)
# w00t be in r00t

# Config ------------------------------------------------
outfile="linux_info.txt"
#--------------------------------------------------------

#### uncomment (set -x) for debug 
# set -x 


checkroot() { 
    if [ $UID -ne 0 ] ; then
        echo "User has insufficient privilege."
        exit 4
    fi
}


function shouldSkip {
  read -p "$*" line
  test "$line" = 'n' -o "$line" = 's'
  return $?
}


header() { 
    echo '' | tee -a $outfile
    echo '----------------------' | tee -a $outfile
    echo "[*] $title" | tee -a $outfile
    echo '----------------------' | tee -a $outfile
}

function pause(){
   read -p "$*"
}


display_os() { 
    title="System"
    header $title
    dmidecode -t 1 | grep -i 'serial' | sed 's/^ *//' | tee  $outfile
    cat /etc/*-release | tee -a $outfile
    dmidecode -t system -q | egrep -i 'Manufacturer: |Product|UUID' | \
    sed 's/^ *//' | tee -a $outfile
    /usr/bin/ipmitool bmc info | egrep -i 'Firmware revision' | tee  -a $outfile
    dmidecode -t bios -q | egrep -i 'version|vendor' | \
    sed 's/^ *//' | tee -a $outfile
}

display_network_oob() { 
    title="Drac-Info"
    header $title
    ipmitool lan print | egrep -i 'IP Address|MAC Address|Default Gateway IP|Subnet Mask' | tee -a $outfile
}

display_networking() {
    title="Networking"
    header $title
    ifconfig -a | tee -a $outfile
}

display_bonding() { 
    if [ -f /proc/net/bonding/bond0 ] ; then
        title="Bonding"
        header $title
        cat /proc/net/bonding/bond0 | sed 's/^ *//' | tee -a $outfile
    fi
}

display_switch_info() { 
    if [ -f /usr/sbin/lldpctl ] ; then
        title="Switch-Port-Information"
        header $title
        lldpctl | egrep '(Interface|VLAN|PortDescr|SysName)' | \
        sed 's/^ *//' | tee -a $outfile
        else
            echo "Switch file LLDPCTL does not exist skipping"
    fi
}

show_disks_dell() {
    if [ -f /opt/MegaRAID/MegaCli/MegaCli64 ] ; then 
        title="Dell-Raid"
        header $title
        /opt/MegaRAID/MegaCli/MegaCli64 -PDList -aAll |  \
        egrep -i 'count|^Device Id: |firmware state' |  \
        grep -v 'Count: 0' | \
        perl -p -e 's/Firmware state: (.*)$/Firmware state: $1\n/' | tee -a $outfile
        /opt/MegaRAID/MegaCli/MegaCli64 -LDInfo -Lall -aALL | \
        egrep -i 'virtual|cache|state|raid level|name|size|number' | tee -a $outfile
        else
            echo "skipping Dell disk check"
     fi
}

show_battery_dell() { 
    if [ -f /opt/MegaRAID/MegaCli/MegaCli64 ]; then
        title="Dell-Battery"
        header $title
        /opt/MegaRAID/MegaCli/MegaCli64 -AdpBbuCmd -GetBbuStatus -a0 | \
        egrep -i 'isSOHGood|Charger Status|Capacity|Relative|Charging' | \
        sed 's/^ *//' | tee -a $outfile
        else
            echo "skipping Dell battery check"
    fi
}

show_disks_hp() { 
    if [ -f /usr/sbin/hpacucli ]; then
        title="HP-Raid"
        header $title
        hpacucli ctrl all show config detail | \
        sed 's/^ *//' | tee -a $outfile 
    else
        echo "skipping HP disk check"
    fi
}

show_battery_hp() { 
    if [ -f /usr/sbin/hpacucli ]; then
        title="HP-Battery"
        header $title
        hpacucli ctrl all show status | \
        sed 's/^ *//' | tee -a $outfile
    else
        echo "skipping HP battery check"
    fi
}

display_dimms() {
        title="Memory"
        header $title
        cat /proc/meminfo|grep MemTotal | tee -a $outfile
        free -g | tee -a $outfile
        dmidecode -t Memory Device -q |egrep -i 'Size:|Type: D|Locator: D' | tee -a $outfile


}

sel_list() {
    title="SEL"
    header $title
    ipmitool sel elist | tee -a $outfile
}




# Where the magic happens -------------------------------------
# TODO: Add Optarg Support
# http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/getopts_tutorial




checkroot

pause 'Press [Enter] key to continue into DONUTS Version: 0.1.1. ..'
service ipmi start


if ! shouldSkip 'Press [Enter] key to continue, [n] or [s] to skip "Display OS".   '
then
  display_os
fi

if ! shouldSkip 'Press [Enter] key to continue, [n] or [s] to skip "Display Network OOB".   '
then
  display_network_oob
fi

if ! shouldSkip 'Press [Enter] key to continue, [n] or [s] to skip "Display Network".   '
then
  display_networking
fi

if ! shouldSkip 'Press [Enter] key to continue, [n] or [s] to skip "Display Bonding".   '
then
  display_bonding
fi


if ! shouldSkip 'Press [Enter] key to continue, [n] or [s] to skip "Display Switch Port Information".   '
then
  display_switch_info
fi

if ! shouldSkip 'Press [Enter] key to continue, [n] or [s] to skip "Display Memory".   '
then
  display_dimms
fi

if ! shouldSkip 'Press [Enter] key to continue, [n] or [s] to skip "System Event List".   '
then
  sel_list
fi


if ! shouldSkip 'Press [Enter] key to continue, [n] or [s] to skip "HP RAID".   '
then
  show_disks_hp
fi

if ! shouldSkip 'Press [Enter] key to continue, [n] or [s] to skip "HP RAID Battery".   '
then
  show_battery_hp
fi

if ! shouldSkip 'Press [Enter] key to continue, [n] or [s] to skip "Dell RAID".   '
then
  show_disks_dell
fi

if ! shouldSkip 'Press [Enter] key to continue, [n] or [s] to skip "Dell RAID Battery".   '
then
  show_battery_dell
fi

pause 'Press [Enter] key to continue. ..'
service ipmi stop


cat << "EOF"
          _ _,---._
       ,-','       `-.___
      /-;'               `._
     /\/          ._   _,'o \
    ( /\       _,--'\,','"`. )
     |\      ,'o     \'    //\
     |      \        /   ,--'""`-.
     :       \_    _/ ,-'         `-._
      \        `--'  /                )
       `.  \`._    ,'     ________,','
         .--`     ,'  ,--` __\___,;'
          \`.,-- ,' ,`_)--'  /`.,'
           \( ;  | | )      (`-/
             `--'| |)       |-/         DONUTS Version: 0.1.1
               | | |        | |
               | | |,.,-.   | |_
               | `./ /   )---`  )
              _|  /    ,',   ,-'
             ,'|_(    /-<._,' |--,
             |    `--'---.     \/ \
             |          / \    /\  \
           ,-^---._     |  \  /  \  \
        ,-'        \----'   \/    \--`.
       /            \              \   \
EOF
```